# What is the better way to transform and put text inside linear layout

Tags: android, layout

Today i have two questions in android topic(sorry i'm novice)

I have a page in **html** and i put one text and inernaly with javascript i `transform` this text to other format and structure. I want do it same with android but i don't know how do it.

#### example:

```
hello team  

i'm  @SonickSeven and it is a link https://example.com/test
```

my insternal service transform it to:

```
hello team 

i&#x27;m  [user][SonickSeven] and it is a link  [link][https://example.com/test]
```

and my HTML system shows it:

[image]

I use `aref, p, spam` tags to do it.

In android i can separate the words and do it:

i created `textView` for each and i return a array with much textViews and later i put thoose textView in the linearLayout, but my problem is that thoose elements don't **word wrap**

#### Android code

```
public static TextView[] splitStringMsg(String text, Context ctx){
    String[] partes=text.split("\n| ");
    TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[partes.length];
    for(int i=0; i<partes.length; i++){
        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(ctx);
        if(partes[i].indexOf("[user]")>-1){
            rowTextView.setText(partes[i]);
            System.out.println("Ft have user tag "+partes[i]);
            rowTextView.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.defecto_color_text_nick_tabla));
            rowTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }else{
            rowTextView.setText(partes[i]);
            System.out.println("Ft doesn't have user tag");
            rowTextView.setTextColor(ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.defecto_color_text_tabla));
        }

        myTextViews[i]=rowTextView;
    }
    System.out.println(text+" --Es un texto: ");
    Log.e("FT cantiada de eso", String.valueOf(partes.length));
    return myTextViews;
}
```

#### Android results

[image]

I'm doing good it or exists other best way to do it and how do i do for add elements with `word warp`

Thanks community for help me

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to use `Spannables`.
There are plenty of examples and tutorials about it on the Internet

Comment: But it works for create a link(open link like a href)?

Comment: I haven't worked with URLs, but it has URLSpan
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But why do you not put it like answer, i could check it like my solution for other user search the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use `URLSpan`:

```
        ...
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("This is a url to ");
        SpannableString stackOverflow = new SpannableString("Stackoverflow");
        URLSpan urlSpan = new URLSpan("stackoverflow.com");
        stackOverflow.setSpan(urlSpan, 0 , stackOverflow.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        spannableStringBuilder.append(spannableString);
        spannableStringBuilder.append(stackOverflow);
        mTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
        ...
```